# What are the best fishing locations on the new farm layouts?

Tags: stardew-valley

According to the [official wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Fish#Prime_Locations) certain locations in the game provide higher quality fish than others. Specifically, tiles far from land, near/in dark water, and near logs provide better results. On the new fishing based farm layout, what are the best locations, if any?

What about fishing spots on the other new layouts that have a decent amount of water (wilderness farm and maybe forest farm)?

Comment: There is nothing special about those locations specifically, you just want to cast as far away from land as possible.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer So the wiki is wrong on the other aspects? Do we have any confirmation of such? (And ofc, checking the game's source is the best confirmation of all. Or word from the dev) If so, post an answer saying so, and I'll accept. It'd save folks some time running to specific tiles to fish.

Comment: I can go look at the code if you'd like, but it might take a while. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I just finished looking at the code and I can confirm what I noticed while playing: the only factor that changes a fish's quality is how far from land you can get the bobber, in all directions.

From where the bobber (B) lands, imagine many squares centered on that tile. Any square that's completely free of land, or any kind of tile that the player can stand on, will change the odds to favour higher quality fish, with the max at 6 tiles in all directions.

```
3333333
3222223
3211123
321B123
3211123
3222223
3333333
```

Something like that.

Comment: Ha, awesome effort/response man. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: In the entire map? I'll let someone else do that.

Comment: Does the pier on the beach count as "land" for the purposes of fish quality?

Comment: @MageXy Any walkable tile, I'll edit that